# Font-family is not Supporting in IE and MAC Browsers

Tags: html, css, macos, internet-explorer, fonts

Here is my code with the `font-family:"Open Sans light";` It works fine in chrome, firefox browsers, **but it is not supporting in Mac and IE browsers**

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/5T3wq/4/)

**CSS CODE:**

```
#currentdate {
font-family: open sans light !important;
background-color:yellow;
}
```

Also my code for this font which works fine, But in the same browser, I opened `new tab` and when i compile this code it `shows different font`, so this font does not supported, why this is happening.

If you have any idea, I need this font `font-family:"Open Sans light";` should support in all browsers.

Comment: Given that I don't have any variety of Open Sans installed on my Mac, why would you expect that to work?

Comment: Please don't confuse Mac (Macintosh) and MAC (Media Access Control).

Comment: I tried on Safari on my Mac, and loaded it on a virtual machine running IE8 and IE9 and then tried in Firefox and Chrome all came out fine.

Comment: @TheLegend: But i used in my project, it shows more variations, Why is it not supporting?

Comment: Show enough code to let others reproduce your problem. Are you using Open Sans fonts locally, or via `@font-face`, or maybe as hosted by Google? Exactly how? Also show a real example, with some HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Fonts can be a sticky issue cross browser. what we have done to achieve consistency is to use a third party font "source" like [google fonts](https://www.google.com/fonts) or [web fonts](http://www.fonts.com/web-fonts)  from fonts.com the thing is the font may be browser specific. Like some versions of IE not supporting SVG so some dynamic fonts will never work.

Try looking for a standard that is pulled from a single source.

Comment: Is there any way to support for all browser the same font font-family:"Open Sans light";

Comment: You would need specify a central locale where the font will be stored. because each system, windows, Mac, ubuntu all have there own fonts installed. there are a few that are shared amongst them all but they are your standard ones nothing fancy http://www.macworld.com/article/1144660/xplatype.html

Answer (score 0):

To be extra safe you could try the @font-face tag and embed the font into your website:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'open sans light';
  src: url('filepath/open-sans-light.ttf');
}
```

There's plenty of free online resources to help you convert your .tff(or any other file type) into all the correct font filetypes so that it's available across all browsers. They'll even provide you with the css needed too!

http://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator

Or you could use the ever popular Google Fonts (https://www.google.com/fonts)

Comment: Yha , what you are saying is correct , But i already tried this way, Now also getting changes between different browsers, why it is not supporting for some browsers like IE & MAC.

Comment: When you use a generator like the one provide above, it provides you with various font formats that are used for cross browser compatibility, so as long as you are using the CSS they give you, there's no issues. Most versions of IE support @font-face, and as far as it not working on a mac, as a mac user myself it has always worked for me. The change between browsers is because each browser renders the font differently, this might help: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/9972/how-can-i-make-fonts-render-the-same-way-across-different-web-browsers